# Error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory. Directory pointed explicitly

Tags: gcc

I got the following error :

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I do not how to solve it because I explicitly tell gcc where to search. I call:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -std=c99 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft  -I/home/charlie/projects/epsionic-nrf/Inc -c Src/Clock.c -o Obj/Debug/Clock.o -L/home/charlie/arm-none-eabi/lib
```

I know that cc1 is inside the following directory:

```
/home/charlie/arm-none-eabi/lib
```

I have already checked if `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX` is defined in my environment but it is not.

Does anyone know what the issue is?